# What are some good written and simple modules I should look at to learn Magento?

Tags: module

I've created a few very simple Magento modules. Now I want to look at very good written code for Magento modules. It shouldn't be a huge module, maybe some news or blog module, I don't know. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I think this is a valid and good question. Where can I find good magento code to learn from. Please don't close this question.

Answer (score 1):

We organize hackathons from time to time. Most of the modules are technically great:

https://github.com/magento-hackathon